# Android- how to decode html string with images to textview

Tags: android, html, string, textview, drawable

i want to know how to decode an html string containg images and text to a textview?

Example string:

```
String s="<p dir="ltr"><img src="ic_7.png"><img src="ic_4.png">byebye<img src="ic_13.png"><img src="ic_8.png">lol<img src="ic_9.png">asd<img src="ic_2.png"></p>"
```

I was using :

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(s),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Try using a WebView instead of the TextView.

Comment: but the images are in drawable folder, not online...and i'm using a bubbletextview, the bubble background doesn't work with webview